# AsyncTask help needed to understand

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have researched before posting this but couldn't really get a clear answer so I came here. In these lines of code, I want to understand what exactly they do. I am coming from a cpp background and things here are really different..

```
new DisplayImageFromURL((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image))
                .execute("http://www.tmonews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/androidfigure.jpg");
```

what exactly does this code do? There is a private class declared beneath this in my codes but I dont know what info it passes to the next class.

```
 private class DisplayImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Loading...");
            pd.show();
        }
        public DisplayImageFromURL(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return mIcon11;

        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

what does this do in this code? And what does that curly braces mean here?

```
public DisplayImageFromURL(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }
```

And this last one..where is it getting the URl from?

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
```

Comment: read the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: 'what does that curly braces mean here?' Maybe read about Java as well: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-092-introduction-to-programming-in-java-january-iap-2010/index.htm

Comment: Sir I have read the official android documents

Comment: yes but you may want to start with the very basics of programming - no offens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public DisplayImageFromURL(ImageView bmImage) {
this.bmImage = bmImage;
}
```

Above is the constructor for this class. Since it's a method, curly braces are used to show where method starts and ends.

The urls are parameters and they are what is passed to execute method.

```
new DisplayImageFromURL((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image))
.execute("http://www.tmonews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/androidfigure.jpg");
```

AsyncTask Params, Progress, Result